# update one table by inserting values from another table SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have two tables `bottle` and `case` that are filled out. They both have a column labeled `case_id` however in `bottle` table all the values are `0` while in case table they have the correct `id`.

How can I update the first table bottle values `0` with the new values from other table case? I believe I will need to use an `UPDATE` or `INSERT` or `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How do you insert your values in the first place to `bottle`? It seems that something is going wrong in your `insert` into `bottle`

Comment: Is there something other than the case_id in the table that you can use to match them? If not then there is no SQL solution here. You will have to go to the cellar with a notepad and write down which bottle is in which case. I hope it's a small cellar :-)

Comment: It would be helpful to include the table definitions for the two tables - what columns/types are in each.

Answer (score 1):

If you give more detail for table struct will be better

```
UPDATE b SET b.case_id=c.case_id
FROM bottle AS b INNER JOIN [Case] AS c ON b.some_coloumn=c.some_cloumn
```